# How to put a google map function inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, android-fragments

Well, below is my example, I have a main activity in Android, and I have create a toolbar, and there is a sub function called location which I will call some location function here.
It is coded in a fragment because I need to create a fragment when I get into the sub function after I click the icon from the toolbar.

I have got how to show the google map inside a activity. But I failed to show it in a fragment.
What I can do is just to call a onActivityCreated inside a fragment. However, although the program works fine, but the layout will omit the toolbar.(I am not good at English, if you don't understand what I am talking about, just ask me for details:))

So does anyone could help me to figure out how to call some google location services such as find the png and lat, or showing the google map inside a fragment? My fragment code is in below:

LocationFragment.java:

```
public class LocationFragment extends MapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View location_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
        return location_layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **fragment class** will be:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

       // initialize it to avoid a NPE
       try {
           MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
       } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) { }

       mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
       mapView.onCreate(bundle);

       // check if the map is null
       if (map == null) {
           map = ((MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
       }

       // add a marker
       map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Here!"));

       return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bundle = savedInstanceState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       mapView.onDestroy();
       super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override  
    public void onLowMemory() {  
        super.onLowMemory();  
        mapView.onLowMemory();  
    }  
}
```

And finally, your layout **fragment_map**:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

*He' we go* to show your map inside a fragment! See **[a little post](http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287)** on it and **[the reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)** from Google.

For user's Location, a bit of reading is necessary, just to know more about it: **[Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)** (read carefully, everything is tell there). You'll need a `Location Manager` and a `Location Listener`.
First of all, you need this implements:

```
// The implement
implements LocationListener { [...] }
```

With this listener, you will able to have and update the location of the device via GPS or network. Don't forget to test the status of the device's service, something like this:

```
// Getting Google Play availability status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
```

This code below is an example to get the current location inside a fragment:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

    private Marker marker;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    static final LatLng NEWYORK = new LatLng(40.75, -74.03);

    @Override  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);

        // ... 
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        // ...
        if (map != null) initMap();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            getGPS();
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);    
        }
        // ...

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getGPS();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        outGPS();
    }

    public void getGPS() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
    }

    public void outGPS() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        // get the latitude and the longitude
        final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("lat : ");
        msg.append(location.getLatitude());
        msg.append( "; lng : ");
        msg.append(location.getLongitude());
        // display it on a toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // final latlng with these above to update the position on a marker
        final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 1));
        marker.setPosition(latLng);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
        if("gps".equals(provider)) {
            desabonnementGPS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
        if("gps".equals(provider)) {
            abonnementGPS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras) { }

    private void initMap() {
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("New-York").position(NEWYORK));
        marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("I am here!").position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
    }
}
```

Then you create the manager and after you update the current location with the `onLocationChanged` method. There some good tutorials about it: **[a tutorial by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)** (it might be help) and **[another tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)** (can help you too).

> You have a lot of tips on **[this blog](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html)**. Very simple, very comprehensive.

**NOTE2:** DON'T FORGET TO ADD THE PERMISSIONS IN YOUR MANIFEST.

I hope, I answered clearly and this will be useful.
Happy coding!

Comment: Hey Fllo, thanks your advice.
But I want to create a map view inside a fragment, say I have create a Fragment class, so it should be a onCreateView method instead of onCreate, because it is a fragment not an activity...

Comment: Hep! I saw that, I updated my answer according to your need. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: But here's another question comes, when I would like to add a locationManager, it brings me into unreachable code. public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View location_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
  return location_layout;
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: When your in a fragment (in onCreatedView method) you must return the view (your layout) always **at the end** of this method. So, try to set your location before `return location_layout`.

Comment: It brings a null pointer exception. because i have set some string into a layout before return the layout, then what's next step?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. You can compare and see how it does. And when you have some troubles with the solution (*the unreachable code*, the *nullpointerexception*..), edit your answer and add your new code (via the comments, it's sometimes difficult to find the issue) or create a new question for understand what happened. HTH.

Comment: Also, adding some string in a layout is **always** attached from the view of the fragment (in this case `v`). So findViewById became `v.findViewById`, don't forget it. ;)

Comment: Hey man, you know what? you fix my problem! That's all I want! "v.findViewById" this sentence, you are a good guider!